# Why can't I add a existing MediaItem to an existing Album using the online Api Explorer?

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm using the `albumId` that I got from the `albums.list` method. It is, in my eyes, a valid `ID`, because I can use the `albums.get` method to get the album.

I'm using the `mediaItemId` that I got from the `mediaItems.list` method. It is, again in my eyes, a valid ID, because i can use the `mediaItems.get` method to get the mediaItem.

Both work without problems!

When I'm trying to add the `mediaItem` to the album, using the albums.batchAddMediaItems method, I get an

`error: No permission to add media items to this album.`

[image: The request]
[image: The error]

I used `OAuth 2.0` and checked every scope that can be checked.

Comment: I get the same problem. But it works if i dont target an album. Very strange.

Answer (score 5):

I asked the same question. I posted an answer there:
[Google photos api adding photos to existing album is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738766/google-photos-api-adding-photos-to-existing-album-is-broken/58740231#58740231)

See "Media items can be created only within the albums created by your app. For more information, see Authentication and authorization scopes." from this link: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media

The jist of it is that google api wont let you programatically modify an album that wasnt also created programatically. If you create the album via the api, get the response with the ID and then append to the album afterward. You shouldn't see that error response.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worse than this, no?  Google won't allow you to (programmatically) add media that has NOT been uploaded by your app to an album ... even if you/your-app (programmatically) created that album

So the batchAddMediaItemsToAlbum functionality only supports the use-case that your app uploads media, and you want to organise them into albums.  But not the (surely more common?) use-case where you want to (programmatically) organise the chaos of GPhotos

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).