# Can't add an existing Media Item to a new Album via Google Photos API

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

### Goal

I am attempting to programmatically copy existing Media Items from one album to a newly created album.

For example, I have a photo with Media Item ID of `p001` and it currently lives in an album that respectively has an ID of `a001`. I have programmatically created a new album of ID `a002`. I want to add photo `p001` to album `a002` programmatically.

### Problem

The following error appears when making the API call to add the photo to the album:

```
"Request must contain a valid upload token."
```

There is a related issue of the [inability to add media items to existing albums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738766/google-photos-api-adding-photos-to-existing-album-is-broken/58740231#58740231) and my suspicion is that this is related, but not well documented (or maybe has poor discoverability).

Is this expected behavior?

#### Full Error Log

```
Error adding photo ID <REDACTED> to album ID <REDACTED> <HttpError 400 when requesting https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate?alt=json returned "Request must contain a valid upload token.". Details: "Request must contain a valid upload token.">
```

### My Implementation

I am attempting this via a Python 3.11 script as follows, where:

- `credentials.json` contains the OAuth credentials to my API (I have verified this works, as I have successfully created an album programmatically).
- `photos.csv` is a CSV file where the rows are defined as `album_name,album_id,photo_name,photo_id`, such as `Album 1,a001,Photo 1,p001`.

```
import csv
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Path to your '.json' file for the new account
CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = './credentials.json'

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary']

def create_album(service, album_title):
    album_request_body = {
        'album': {'title': album_title}
    }
    created_album = service.albums().create(body=album_request_body).execute()
    return created_album['id']

def add_photo_to_album(service, photo_id, album_id):
    try:
        service.mediaItems().batchCreate(body={
            'newMediaItems': [{'simpleMediaItem': {'uploadToken': photo_id}}],
            'albumId': album_id
        }).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error adding photo ID {photo_id} to album ID {album_id}: {e}")

def main():
    # Authenticate with the new account
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH, SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    service = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials=creds, static_discovery=False)

    # Track the created albums to avoid duplicates
    created_albums = {}

    with open('photos.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip header

        for album_name, _, photo_name, photo_id in reader:
            temp_album_name = f"{album_name}-TEMP"

            if temp_album_name not in created_albums:
                created_albums[temp_album_name] = create_album(service, temp_album_name)

            add_photo_to_album(service, photo_id, created_albums[temp_album_name])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Look at `{'uploadToken': photo_id}` in your code. `uploadToken` needs to be a token you've received from Google after uploading the file. Only after uploading it can you add it to Photos library using that received `uploadToken` (see https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media). The `photo_id` which you are using comes from your .csv file and doesn't appear to be what it needs to be. (An uploadToken I've just generated is a very long string, 488 characters)